# Reset model pose in ignition

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a way to reset model poses in ignition similar to Gazebo Edit->Reset Model Poses?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25451/reset-model-pose-in-ignition/) by [athackston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28658/athackston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's no interface for that on Ignition yet. See this issue:

https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/issues/203

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0